# Dependency Injection for `trait`

Tags: scala, dependency-injection

Given the following `FooService`:

```
scala> trait FooService { 
     |   def go: Int 
     | }
defined trait FooService
```

There's also a `MainService`, which represents a main method.

```
scala> trait MainService extends FooService { 
     |   def f = go + 42
     | }
defined trait MainService
```

`FooService` can have a fake (for testing) and a real implementation (hits DB, for example):

```
scala> object FakeService extends FooService { 
     |   def go = 10
     | }
defined object FakeService

scala> object RealService extends FooService {
     |   def go = 55 // in reality, let's say it hit the DB and got a value
     | }
defined object RealService
```

It seems to me that adding a "runner" class/trait, i.e. running `sbt run` would result in that class's execution, would be feasible. It would look like:

```
scala> class Main extends MainService {
     |   override def go = RealService.go
     | }
defined class Main
```

And I could define a test too:

```
scala> class Test extends MainService {
     |   override def go = FakeService.go
     | }
defined class Test
```

I'm not so sure that this is the idiomatic way of defining a real versus test `MainService`. Please let me know.

Comment: You can extend FakeService/RealService from MainService and use them. Or you can make FakeService/RealService traits and mix them to Main/Test.

Comment: Check out Google Guice for an easy to use solution for DI. I found that good to start with.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the popular cake pattern which is also known as a "Scala way" of doing dependency injection.

Jon did a great [blog post](http://jonasboner.com/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/) about this with a walkthrough (he listed also some alternatives).

Firstly, the trait for the `FooService`:

```
trait FooServiceComponent {
  val fooService: FooService

  trait FooService {
    def go: Int
  }
}
```

That's saying, we need two things: 1. the actual object, and 2. its definition/implementation.  Both namespaced together.  Nice.  Here are the `Fake` and `Real` versions:

```
trait FakeService extends FooServiceComponent {
  class FakeService extends FooService {
    def go = 10
  }
}

trait RealService extends FooServiceComponent {
  class RealService extends FooService {
    def go = 55
  }
}
```

Now, for the `MainService`:

```
trait MainServiceComponent { this: FooServiceComponent =>
  val mainService: MainService

  class MainService extends FooService {
    def f = go + 42
    def go = fooService.go // using fooService
  }
}
```

Note the self-typing `this: FooServiceComponent` which is a Scala way of saying that `MainServiceComponent` has a dependency on `FooServiceComponent`.  If you try to instantiate `MainServiceComponent` without mixing in any `FooServiceComponent` then you will get a compile-time error. Nice. :)

Now, let's create the `Test` and `Main` objects with different traits:

```
object Test extends MainServiceComponent with FakeService {
  val mainService = new MainService()
  val fooService = new FakeService()
}

object Main extends MainServiceComponent with RealService {
  val mainService = new MainService()
  val fooService = new RealService()
}
```

Note that because of namespacing, `FakeService` can't be accessed in `Main` because it's not mixed in.  Nice. :)  Note also that you delay any instantiation of class until this point, which is convenient in that you can easily use a registry or mocking library to substitute them all in one place.

Results:

```
println(Test.mainService.f) // -> 52
println(Main.mainService.f) // -> 97
```

I hope this helps.